# Can I do the equivalent of jmping to a label by saving and modifying the Instruction Pointer?

Tags: assembly, x86

To start with: there is absolutely no practical reason for this. It seems like it should work, yet it just isn't. My strategy is to use `call` to get `%eip` and `popq` it into `%rax`. So now `%eip` is (in theory) stored in `%rax`. Then, when I want to loop back to that spot of my code, I `call %rax`. But this does not happen. Instead of looping back, execution just keeps on going on to the next line! My full code is here:

```
.section .data
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
movl $10, %edi # number of fibnum we hunt
movl $0, %ebx # 1st fibnum
movl $1, %esi

call _saveIP
_saveIP:
popq %rax

## Check if %edi is 0
## (thus meaning %ebx is nth fibnum)
## and if so, exit loop
decl %edi
cmpl $0, %edi
je loop_exit

## core Fibonnaci algorithm
## (hold %esi in tmp register %edx,
## esi = esi + ebx,
## ebx = edx)
movl %esi, %edx
addl %ebx, %esi
movl %edx, %ebx

## This should jump up us back up, but doesn't!
jmpq *(%rax)

## Once loop completes...
loop_exit:
movl $1, %eax
int $0x80
```

I've read about `jmp` using indirect, rather than direct, jumping. That sounds pretty relevant but I'm not sure what it really means, and my research into `jmp`/`call` all say they just go to the address in memory you provide them. What should I be doing differently to make this work? Thanks!

Comment: I am aware of the irony that in my quest to do this using %EIP instead of jmping to a label I use both a label and a jmp. But my point is that I *really* want to do this by manipulating the instruction pointer.

Comment: It should be `jmpq *%rax` without parentheses. Note that will loop back to the `popq %rax` since that was the return address. That is probably not what you want. Also in 64 bit mode you can easily get the address using a `lea`.

Comment: `jmpq *%rax`, but there is a logic error - you'd jump to `pop %rax` instruction, and will corrupt your stored jump pointer for the next iteration. On a side note, it is recommended to post code on the question, rather than off-site resource. And what you are doing is already indirect jumping.

Comment: @AlejandroAlvarado Have you tried using `lea` to get the value of the instruction pointer instead?

Comment: lea did the trick! Thank you so much! Assembly is so fun. If someone wants to post the lea approach I'll gladly accept. Y'all are life savers.

Comment: @AlejandroAlvarado if you succeed in using lea, you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the value of the instruction pointer at a given location using a `lea` instruction:

```
    lea .(%rip), %rax
```

The symbol `.` refers to the current location, `.(%rip)` uses a `rip`-relative addressing mode to refer to `.`.  The same method can be used to get the address of any other label, too.

Another way with a slightly shorter encoding is to use a `call` followed by a `pop`.  Looks like this:

```
    call 0f
0:  pop %rax
```

Note that by design, this can only be used to get the address of the instruction immediately following the `call` instruction.  This use of `call` is special-cased in all modern processor's return predictors (except Via's, but those aren't exactly modern) and doesn't cause performance issues even though the `call` is not paired with a corresponding `ret`.

Comment: Also worth mentioning you can use a relative offset from RIP instead of asking the assembler to calc the displacement to an absolute.  In AT&T syntax, `lea -7(%rip), %rax` is a relative offset of -7 (not the absolute address `-7` addresses relative to the current location), so it's actually equivalent to `lea .(%rip), %rax` because that LEA instruction is 7 bytes long.  But yes, if you want to do relative addressing relative to the *start* of the LEA, then `. +- number(%rip)` is handy syntax.